# a tag - writing without specifying type

Tags: html, path

I cannot find an answer to this question. I guess it could be a general question that apply to all languages, but I am working in HTML right now.

So entering this:

```
<a href="foo">foo</a>
```

Will it look for a folder named "foo" or a file named "foo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working on HTTP: No. It will ask the server for an HTTP resource called `foo`.

If you're dealing with `file:` URIs, then it will look for a file called `foo` … but a directory is just a special type of file.

Either way, it will only start to care about what type of resource it gets *when it gets it* (i.e. not at the time it asks for it).